# Are these commercially dried mushrooms still safe to eat?

Tags: mushrooms

[the mix is still well in date but a few of the mushrooms look potentially mouldy? mushroom container[image: third image]**enter image description here**][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/np9lF.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SA!  Leaving aside that all "are these safe to eat" questions get closed as duplicates, I don't see any mold in the photo.

Comment: I'd like to share a close -up of where i think I spot mould but is it possible to add a second photo? Otherwise, I could edit the photo to delete that one and use the close-up image instead. I'd appreciate your opinion.

Comment: I wouldn't bother.  We really don't answer "is this safe to eat" questions.

Comment: Yeah, I guess if there's any doubt, then it's doubtful and should be binned. But I'll ask the supplier and if the answer is interesting, will post about it here. Thanks for replying : )

Comment: The asnwer is always the same: it's up to you and your personal level of risk, but the general rule is "if you're asking you should probably throw it out".

Comment: Hey, just wanted to let you know - I contacted the stockist and they sent my photos and query to the supplier who said that if the product was still in date then fine to eat although they mentioned that they couldn't vouch for how it had been stored while with me. I was going to keep using these dried mixed mushrooms but when opened them most recently, there were a few white specs on a lighter variety too so they all went in the bin : )